# Precedents for member states unilaterally overriding EU trade policy (or at least attempting to do that)?

Tags: european-union, trade

> The European Commission has rejected bans introduced by Poland and Hungary on Ukrainian grain imports.
>
> The two countries said the measures were necessary to protect their farming sectors from cheap imports.
>
> The ban applies to grains, dairy products, sugar, fruit, vegetables and meats and will be in force until the end of June.
>
> The Commission said it was not up to individual member states to make trade policy.
>
> -- https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65292698

And [now](https://www.rferl.org/a/bulgaria-ukrainian-grain-food-ban-hungary/32370719.html) Bulgaria and Slovakia too:

> Bulgaria on April 19 announced that it will temporarily ban the import of grain, milk, meat, and other food products from Ukraine, following in the footsteps of fellow European Union member states Poland, Hungary, and Slovakia.

Have some EU countries tried to do something like this before? The article doesn't mention any precedent.